# Generation of K-bit string in JAVA

Tags: java, cryptography, key-generator

During a crypto course is have to generate keys of a certain length, 128 bit in my base, but I am not sure, what the easiest way to do so is?

It is regarding Garbling Circuits if it has any interest.

So basically I just need to be able to generate:

1000100101110101...

At random with certain length. Can write some code to do so myself, but isn't there some easier way?

For now my solution is to make a byte array of length 8 and then use SecureRandom to randomize it, but then I am not able to do binary operations on the entire array :/

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html

Comment: You can do binary operations on bytes. A byte array is nothing more than ... an array of bytes so you only have to iterate over all the bytes.

Comment: Actually, most symmetric algorithms will be implemented using int (32 bits) or long (64 bits) operations internally. Only the interface is handling octets as that has become the primary data size for computers since 1960 or so.